# Delphi Hydra visual plugin border issuse if using styles in host app

Tags: delphi, plugins, remobjects, hydra

If creating a delphi hydra host application and then load a delphi hydra visual plugin on It, then a dialog border appears for visual plugin. this borders appears if using styles in delphi host(Project>options>application>appearance).
Can you help me?

Comment: You haven't stated any problem. What help do you need?

Comment: The problem is probably that it has a border. OP, you should include a screenshot so we can see what the problem is too.

Comment: @DavidM, screenshot mot needed. In simply if we using hydra plugin in host app a window title appears outside of the plugin(like a dialog border).

Comment: Most of us don't have Hydra, and you shouldn't expect people to go and create a project to see your issue when you can make it easy for us. Also, you didn't mention a window title, just a "border" - a screenshot would have cleared that up quickly. In fact I would have suggested the BorderStyle fix that you seem to have found yourself. As a general rule on SO, try to: include all info where possible; include screenshots if describing a visual issue; don't make people go to unnecessary effort (eg creating their own project just to try to see how a visual bug looks). Make it easy for readers!

Comment: @DavidM, Ok, thanx for your comments. I remember your suggestion in mind. thanx againe.

Comment: No worries, and thankyou for your thanks and future remembering :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
for solving It:
In Host Application we must using this code:

```
HYModuleManager1.CreateVisualPlugin('Yourplugin', Plugin, Panel);
if Plugin.GetObject is TForm then
TForm(Plugin.GetObject).BorderStyle := bsNone;
```

thanx ejay from remobjects:
http://connect.remobjects.com/discussion/comment/14464#Comment_14464